# Convert string with escape characters to double

Tags: c#, string, escaping, double, type-conversion

This might be a silly question, but I'm not sure how to tackle the problem.  How would you convert this string to double:

```
"\"15.4\""
```

The string comes in as:

```
"15.4"
```

I need to see it as a double.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy way is [Convert.ToDouble("15.4".Trim('"'))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble.aspx)

Comment: But the string given is not `"15.4"`, it is `"\"15.4\""`

Answer (score 3):

First trim the quotation marks, then parse the string:

```
string input = "\"15.4\"";
double n = Double.Parse(input.Trim('"'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Using the invariant culture means that the parsing uses the period as decimal separator, regardless of your current culture settings.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = "\"15.4\"";
var d = double.Parse(s.Trim('"'));
```

This only works if the `'"'` characters are known to be at the beginning or end of the string.  If other configurations are possible, the code will have to be a little more complex to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is:

```
double value = Double.Parse("\"15.4\"".Trim('"'));
```

However, I encourage you to look at `Double.TryParse`, so that you can test for `string`s that don't parse to `double`s.

```
double value;
if(!Double.TryParse("\"15.4\"".Trim('"'), out value)) {
   // it didn't parse
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the `'"'` characters contained in the input string.

Comment: you're welcome.  I upvoted your answer to compensate for the downvote that someone else cast.  Lots of correct answers to this question have received downvotes; it's very odd.

Comment: @phoog: Thanks. I +1 you too. Yes, it seems a bit confused here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes, then parse it.

```
var str = "\"15.4\"";
str = str.Replace("\"", "");
var num = double.Parse(str);
```

Comment: This turns invalid strings into valid ones (e.g., `\"15\".4\"`)